# How can i change the Header color of PivotItem Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to change the color of Header inside PivotItem, i tryed a lot but doesn't works.

```
<PivotItem x:Name="PivotInfo" Header="Informações" Margin="0,10,0,-0.5">
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xaml
<Pivot>
  <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock
         Text={Binding} />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

you can style this textblock